# coin specifications values in source code

Tags: litecoin, specification

I am new to Bitcoins.

I wanted to know the specifications of coins inside source code. Can any one tell me,

> *** What are those functions and variable which are responsible to get and
>   set the coin specifications values?

Lets say, Coin 'litecoin' and Source https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin and Coin Specifications are:-

1. Block Time
2. Block Reward
3. Block Time
4. Block Reward
5. Reward Halfing Time
6. Maxcoins
7. Difficulty Retarget Time
8. Coin Maturity Time
9. Confirmation Time
10. Rpcport
11. Port
12. Testnet port

Comment: Consult the bitcoin wiki.

Comment: @JacobTorba I think, this community is dedicated for discussing issues with bitcoins. If I wants to know or consult with someone regarding my issues then stackexchange should welcome my queries.

Comment: If someone is newbie, may be his/her question is not framed properly, then he/she should be encouraged to quest in appropriate manner instead of down vote.Disgusting..!!!

Comment: What is absolutely disgusting is the fact you've managed to ask a question so broad that it literally spans the entire source code. Anyone who would try to answer this all would have to spend hours searching through the source code to find line numbers and functions. The Bitcoin wiki is available to answer such technical questions.

Comment: but if someone who have good knowledge of its source code like @KhanShahrukh then he can suggest the best ways to figure out specifications. It mean, this quest is absolutely right

Comment: Hi Dipendra, welcome to Bitcoin.SE. Your question is pretty broad and, while you were lucky this time, such will often not find an answer. Please check out [about] and [ask] for some information, how SE works and some tips how to submit questions. When someone downvotes, you shouldn't read that as an attack on you, but as somebody voicing his opinion that your "question doesn't show research effort; it is unclear, or not useful". This gives you the opportunity to improve the question, if you come to the conclusion that the feedback is accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not like a website where you pass all the data in one config file and the values will be fetched automatically you need to modify many files.

1. .gitignore - you will change the name of your coin's output file after compiling
2. base58.h - you will choose the letter by which your coin addresses will start
3. src/bitcoinrpc.cpp - you will mention the output of commands on daemon
4. src/checkpoints.cpp - for genesis block
5. src/init.cpp - again changes the outputs of daemon commands, wallet port, testnet port
6. src/irc.cpp - connect to IRC
7. src.main.cpp - choose max coin per block, block time, maturity etc
8. src/main.h - choose total number of coins that will ever be generated

these were the files came in my mind as of now and there are so many more files which needs to be edited.

Comment: And they should learn to read c++ code.

Comment: thanks.. I have seen these specification of a coin are remains same all the time. Does it mean it are statically stored values somewhere in code?. refer [http://mapofcoins.com/]